# Why Docker `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` directory can not be on a overlay2 fs

Tags: docker

When `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` directory is on an overlay2 fs, Docker fails to start with:

```
level=error msg="'overlay2' is not supported over overlayfs" storage-driver=overlay2
level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver overlay2 failed: backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver"
Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver
```

The relevant code seems to be https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/overlay2/overlay.go#L162 but it doesn't explain the why!

Comment: Looks like the commit message explains the reason (https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/0abb8dec3f730f3ad2cc9a161c97968a6bfd0631).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` directory using `xfs_info` whether or not it can be supported the `overlay2`.

For instance,

```
$ xfs_info /var/lib/docker/overlay2 | grep ftype
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
```

If the output is `ftype=1`, then it can be supported the `overlay2`.
Refer [What is d_type and why Docker overlayfs need it](https://linuxer.pro/2017/03/what-is-d_type-and-why-docker-overlayfs-need-it/) for more details.

I hope it help you. :^)

Answer (score 0):

As explained by in a [GitHub commit comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/824c72f4727504e3a8d37f87ce88733c560d4129#r17404678) by the author, overlay on overlay leads to "very quirky behavior" and is thus not supported currently in Docker.

It is not clear why you are attempting to do so. But a common reason is running Docker inside Docker. If this is the case, you can simply mount a folder from host to `/var/lib/docker` inside your container, e.g.:

```sh
docker run -d -v /my/storage:/var/lib/docker docker-in-docker-image
```

In addition, when building an image for Docker-in-Docker, add a `VOLUME /var/lib/docker` statement to your Dockerfile to ensure the folder is a mount point. This is also how the official `docker:dind` image works: https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/master/18.09/dind/Dockerfile#L40